# Does anyone know if you can debug a Service Fabric cluster locally?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

We're having a few issues when trying to debug a local Service Fabric cluster using https. We are able to do it with a lot of faff but surely there must be an easy way.

Also most of our endpoints are HTTP.Sys

TIA

Comment: What kind of issues? Your question is a bit broad. Yes, I have debugged apps deployed to local clusters so it is definitely possible. It is not much different from debugging other apps.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio and want to debug your application?

Comment: Some asked me the following question "Can I add having the ability to run our service fabric apps locally under https as a potential improvement? Having to set the protocol to http in the service manifest and then comment out the endpoint binding policy for each service in the app manifest (and remembering not to check them in), while not a huge deal, is something that feels like could be improved by some Engineery-Type?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment: 
Did you know you can override endpoint behavior using [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-how-to-parameterize-configuration-files) and use different parameters per [environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-how-to-parameterize-configuration-files)?

```xml
<ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="Stateless1Pkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides />
    <ResourceOverrides>
      <Endpoints>
        <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" Port="[Port]" Protocol="[Protocol]" Type="[Type]" />
        <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint1" Port="[Port1]" Protocol="[Protocol1] "/>
      </Endpoints>
    </ResourceOverrides>
    <Policies>
       <EndpointBindingPolicy CertificateRef="TestCert1" EndpointRef="ServiceEndpoint"/>
    </Policies>
</ServiceManifestImport>
```

and

```xml
<Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Port" DefaultValue="" />
    <Parameter Name="Protocol" DefaultValue="" />
    <Parameter Name="Type" DefaultValue="" />
    <Parameter Name="Port1" DefaultValue="" />
    <Parameter Name="Protocol1" DefaultValue="" />
</Parameters>
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-manifest-resources#overriding-endpoints-in-servicemanifestxml).